# Can Odds Ratio be used for a 2x2 table of observed and expected frequencies?

Tags: odds-ratio

*n* = 164 where Group 1 = 58, Group 2 =50, Group 3 = 38 and Group 4 = 18.
The expected frequencies are 25% (41).

1. Would it be appropriate to calculate an Odds Ratio if I wanted to compare Group 1 v Group 4?

(58 x 41)/(41 x 18) = 3.22

2. Would this suggest it is 3.22 times more likely to belong to Group 1 versus Group 4?